# Не обнаруживаются ошибки в Atom C#

Tags: c#, atom

Скачал Atom, поставил: *language-csharp, ide-csharp, linter*, но ошибки по прежнему не подсвечиваются.
Есть ли пакет нужный для шарпа?
Вот скрины, что ошибки нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а почем в этой строчке должна быть ошибка? вы не показали ни одной причины для этого.

Comment: @aepot звучит справедливо. сейчас обновлю скриншоты

Comment: [Говорят](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31119959/12888024) Linter должен этим заниматься. И почитайте комментарии там. Еще [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45985133/12888024).

Comment: @aepot у меня установлен Linter. Он и показывает полоску с ошибками, предупреждениями, но у него нет ни одной настройки в списке пакетов.

Comment: К сожалению (или к счастью), я слез с убунты на десятку уже давно. Visual Studio все-таки удобнее во всех смыслах. Кстати, а [это](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) пробовали?

Comment: @aepot с него перешел на Atom...

Comment: А что насчет [платных](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) решений? Если у вас все серьёзно с дотнетом, то почему бы и нет? Я сам на дотнете не юзал этот вариант, но на php и js - вообще очень хорошо, мне понравилось.